# parent process after child does an exec

Tags: linux

I have a scenario in which after the fork the child executes using the excele() command

a linux system command in which its executes a small shell script .

And the parent does only a wait() after that .  So my question is , does the parent executes

wait after an execle() which the child process executes ?

Thanks
Smita

Comment: are you asking about race condition between `wait()` and `execle()`? ( which one executes first)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you're asking, but the parent is in a wait() system call it will wait there until any child exits. There are other things like signals that will take it out of the exit too.

You do have to be careful in the child process that you don't accidently fall through into the parent code on error.

Answer (score 0):

This (a child process doing some `execve` after its parent `fork`-ed, and the parent `wait`- or `waitpid`-ing it) is a very common scenario; most shells are working this way. You could e.g. `strace -f` an interactive `bash` shell to learn more, or study the source code of simple shells like `sash`

Notice that after a [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) syscall, the parent and the child processes may run simultanously (e.g. at the same time, especially on multi-core machines).

Comment: Ok. So, suppose a test program in  this order as beow does that mean the printf will execute in the below case -:                                                                1)fork (2)if(fork()){ exec("ls") 3)else printf("hi am parent");